# R: filtering elements of large vector that appear in a smaller vector

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose we have a numeric vector. Actually, suppose we have a dataframe consisting of a single column.

```
example = data.frame("column" = rnorm(10000, 10, 3))
```

We'll be treating it as a dataframe in order to use the filter function of the dplyr package.

Also, suppose we have another vector of smaller length. This particular vector is just for the sake of the example. It doesn't necessarily have to be a sequence.

```
numbers = 8:100
```

What I would like to do is to keep those values of the larger vector that are equal to any of the values of the smaller vector and discard those values that are not.

Fair enough. The filter function can do that. Except that I would have to write this:

```
filtered = dplyr::filter(example, column == numbers[1] | column == numbers[2] | ... | column == numbers[length(numbers)])
```

I would have to write the condition `column == numbers[i]` for each of the elements of the numbers vector.

Executing this code

```
filtered = dplyr::filter(example, column == numbers)
```

gives as output a dataframe called filtered that consists of a single column with no rows. There are no rows because, since all the rows of the example dataframe consist of scalars, none of those rows is equal to the whole numbers vector.

Is there an smarter method that doesn't require me to write that condition for each element of the numbers vector?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the operator %in% to check if your values are "in" the vector.

Code:

```
new_data <- old_data %>%
    dplyr::filter(column %in% numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for:

```r
filtered <- dplyr::filter(example, column %in% numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `base R`

```
subset(example, column %in% numbers)
```